# Using a LIKE statement in an IN using a parameter - Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to build a report where I have a char(255) field and I'm giving the initial dataset a statement like such:

```
WHERE an.NoteText like '%COM[1-49CFJO]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

I use the COLLATE to ensure it only picks up these values in capital letters so it doesn't pick up 'comfort' or words with como in them unless they are all caps.

This works in terms of giving me the dataset I want but I then want to filter on the report based on a multi-select parameter @Code.

I can get it to show me values of NoteText when the value is ONLY 'COMF' or 'COM1' by using NoteText IN @Code, but then it won't show anything were the NoteText value is something like "COMF
Customer blah blah blah".  So I need it to pull all records with all the text within the same NoteText instance like it does without the filter added.

I try to use a filter with the expression NoteText IN %@code% or ('%' + @Code + '%') or ('%' & @Code & '%') and in each of these cases it doesn't work even if I only select one value to display at a time.  I'm using SSRS Report Builder.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database and reporting tool you are using.

Comment: @DebjyotiSaha `I'm using SSRS Report Builder`

Comment: Tag that in your question so that people wih that knowledge can see this question.

Answer (score 2):

For the exact code you showed above, you can consolidate it using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator, which supports some primitive regex behavior:

```sql
WHERE an.NoteText like '%COM[1-49CFJO]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: Great, thank you for that piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Unforunately it only just helped clean up the code, the issue is more around not being able to do an IN statement with a Like statement using a parameter(as I understand it).  Every which way I try, I can only get it to show me exact results where the NoteText is ONLY "COM1" or "COMF" in an IN statement.  For some reason when I try using wildcards to be added to the parameter, it doesn't show me any results where my expected result should look like IN (%@Code(0)%, %@Code(1)%) where @Code(0) would be COM1 and @Code(1) would be COMF